# Ipython notebook "from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D" has Value Error

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, 3d, toolkitscriptmanager

I started learning Python 4 months ago and nearly everything went perfect until I got an excercise, where I have to do 3d plots.
For that I have to import mpl_toolkits.mplit3d, but I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c39f93eee133> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic('matplotlib notebook')
      2 from pylab import *
      3 from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
      4 
      5 Lp = 200

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in magic(self, arg_s)
   2334         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
   2335         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2336         return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
   2337 
   2338         #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
   2255                 kwargs['local_ns'] =     sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
   2256             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2257                 result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
   2258             return result
   2259 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py in matplotlib(self, line)

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
191     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
192     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
194 
195         if callable(arg):

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.py in matplotlib(self, line)
 98             print("Available matplotlib backends: %s" % backends_list)
 99         else:
--> 100             gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui)
101             self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
102 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
   3130                 gui, backend =   pt.find_gui_and_backend(self.pylab_gui_select)
   3131 
-> 3132         pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)
   3133         pt.configure_inline_support(self, backend)
   3134 

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in activate_matplotlib(backend)
    270     # the rcParam to update. This needs to be set *before* the module
    271     # magic of switch_backend().
--> 272     matplotlib.rcParams['backend'] = backend
    273 
    274     import matplotlib.pyplot

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in __setitem__(self, key, val)
    808                 warnings.warn(self.msg_depr_ignore % (key, alt))
    809                 return
--> 810             cval = self.validate[key](val)
    811             dict.__setitem__(self, key, cval)
    812         except KeyError:

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py in validate_backend(s)
    144         return s
    145     else:
--> 146         return _validate_standard_backends(s)
    147 
    148 validate_qt4 = ValidateInStrings('backend.qt4', ['PyQt4', 'PySide'])

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/rcsetup.py in __call__(self, s)
     55             return self.valid[s]
     56         raise ValueError('Unrecognized %s string "%s": valid strings are %s'
---> 57                          % (self.key, s,   list(self.valid.values())))
     58 
     59 

ValueError: Unrecognized backend string "nbagg": valid strings are    ['GTK', 'template', 'svg', 'Qt4Agg', 'GTK3Cairo', 'emf', 'WX', 'GTK3Agg', 'CocoaAgg', 'WebAgg', 'TkAgg', 'agg', 'gdk', 'GTKAgg', 'cairo', 'ps', 'pdf', 'pgf',     'WXAgg', 'MacOSX', 'GTKCairo']
```

I really dont know what that means.
Obviously, I have this package, so what is the problem?

Comment: what versions of mpl do you have installed?  `nbagg` was added in 1.4.0.

Comment: it tells me, i have matplotlib 4.0.0

Comment: I have found out, what went wrong: i typed :%matplotlib notebook
from pylab import *
from mpl_toolkit.mplot3d import Axes3D

Comment: #i found out, what went wrong. it was very silly..... i typed `%matplotlib notebook
from pylab import *
from mpl_toolkit.mplot3d import Axes3D` and the only thing i had to do was removing %matplotlib with import matplotlib. sorry for stealing your time and thanks for the help! i think sometimes, i have to sleep about my code xD